# How to set multiple host on apache under one ip address

Tags: apache, ip, host

I'd like to know if it's possible to set multiple host (websites) under one ip address on apache server (running on my centOs server). Problem is, i have no domain name yet, only one single ip address to use.

I tried using "Running different sites on different ports." example posted here (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html), but somehow it doesn't work (return "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." on my firefox).

Here is my virtual host configuration :

Listen 80

Listen 8080

NameVirtualHost 216.244.92.76:80

NameVirtualHost 216.244.92.76:8080

```
<VirtualHost 216.244.92.76:80>

  DocumentRoot "/home/web/shop"
  ServerName my.cellphone.com

  <Directory "/home/web/shop">
     Options All
     AllowOverride All
     Order deny,allow
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 216.244.92.76:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/home/web/pelangi"
  ServerName my.pinkie.com

  <Directory "/home/web/pelangi">
     Options All
     AllowOverride All
     Order deny,allow
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Am i doing something wrong here? Or it's just not possible to set multiple host under one ip address (note that i have no domain name yet) by using different port ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Best Regard,

Tommy

Comment: Okay, i think i've found the problem. Those configuration i posted worked fine just like @shelzmike said. However, my apache configuration read "Listen 80" twice. The 1st is from that configuration above, the other one is from /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. The solution is pretty simple, just comment out or remove one of 'Listen 80' i mention previously, and it worked out just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with both different hostnames or with an IP:PORT as you describe. I do not see anything wrong with you virtual host setup right off. However, my question would be regarding a.) Firewalls, b:) ISP port blocking, etc. have you tried using http://localhost and http://localhost:8080 instead of your IP address?

Also, do you have a router that is portforwarding those ports? Is it working for one and not the other? Sometimes it is the very simple things we overlook.

Mike